# Tell Flask to only store uploads in memory and not to use temporary files

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I'm trying to bypass any local storage when receiving a file. According to the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/#improving-uploads), Flask keeps files in memory if it's "reasonable" otherwise stores them in a temporary location.

I only found a way to limit the size of the request in general with `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH`. How do I control the threshold for the individual file size, or disable using temporary files completely?

Answer (score 3):

The [`Request._get_file_stream`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/wrappers/?highlight=_get_file_stream#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest._get_file_stream) method is used to get file-like objects for storing file uploads. The default implementation uses [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) with a limit of 500 KiB, which keeps the data in memory before writing to a regular temporary file.

Subclass and override the method to always return `BytesIO`. Tell the Flask app to use that class instead of the default one.

```py
from flask.wrappers import Request

class MemoryRequest(Request):
    def _get_file_stream(self, total_content_length, content_type, filename, content_length):
        return BytesIO()

app.request_class = MemoryRequest
```

You could also change the memory threshold by returning `SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size=100_000_000, mode="rb+")` (100 MB for example).

Memory is a much more limited shared resource than disk space, so it usually wouldn't be a good idea to store everything in memory. There should be no reason not to use temporary files.